# Creating an emulator version of Samsung S3

Tags: android, emulation, galaxy, samsung-mobile

Under settings in my Samsung Galaxy S3 -verizon running 4.3, I do not see the "users"
options. Should I have this setting to set up an emulator environment?

Answer (score 2):

Multi-user was only on tablets. You'd need a 3rd party option to force enable this option.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for the 3rd party options?